# How to install a specific commit of a cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins, ionic-framework, screen-orientation

How to install a specific commit of a cordova plugin. I would like to install this branch of *screen orientation* plugin, see
https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/pull/101/commits/99ea202e9b1121fc297ef3bbf0072efa1e6b0335.
But I'm not able to install. Is this even possible? Or which command should I call to install this branch?

I tried differents thing, but without success.

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation:fix-ios-rotate-on-lock
ionic plugin add https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@fix-ios-rotate-on-lock
ionic plugin add https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation#fix-ios-rotate-on-lock
ionic plugin add https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation:99ea202e9b1121fc297ef3bbf0072efa1e6b0335
```

I wasn't able to find the right command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know a workarround, probably not the best solution, but I am going to explain:

copy the commit code: `99ea202e9b1121fc297ef3bbf0072efa1e6b0335`

Go to the main page, and copy the URL of the "Download ZIP" button

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/archive/master.zip

Change "master", for your commit code

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/archive/99ea202e9b1121fc297ef3bbf0072efa1e6b0335.zip

Paste in a navigator, and download it.

Replace your plugin folder, for the downloaded.

Remove platforms, and add them again.

Answer (score 4):

`cordova plugin add git+https://github.com/foo/bar#baz`

Where foo is the org, bar is the project, and baz is the commit hash.

Answer (score 0):

Append `@<version number>` at the end of plugin name while installing the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen@2.0
```

You can find the commit id and perform similar operation for a commit id

Comment: `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@99ea202e9b1121fc297ef3bbf0072efa1e6b0335`doesn't work

Comment: This only works for versions, if its a commit without version, this doesn't work